# redefinition of default parameter error without redefining

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am getting a strange set of error in my Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

I am getting the errors of

```
error C2572: redefinition of default parameter
error C2011: 'class' type redefinition
```

I have checked thoroughly and I know very well that in the function definition, I have not given the default parameter values and I have given default parameter value only in function prototype in the header file.

Also, I am very much sure that no two class has been given the same class name.

Please can anybody tell me what could be the other reasons for getting these set of errors?

Comment: and where is the code? or should we guess?

Comment: Hi @Marius Bancila, thanks for the reply. The code is really huge and it is not possible for me to post it here. I did some trial and error methods and I came to know that it is happening because of inclusion of user defined headerfiles in different files. I believe it is creating circular dependency somewhere. Can you suggest me some ways of overcoming it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not got the exact reason why it was happening, but I have overcome it by using some simple techniques.

I used function overloading concept to avoid default parameter list. It will cause in duplication of code, but it has proved to be very effective.

So something like this

```
void myFunction( int, char * = '\0', char * = '\0' );
```

would become something like this

```
void myFunction( int );
void myFunction( int, char * );
void myFunction( int, char *, char * );
```

In this example, code is getting duplicated two times but it seems to be only work around solution.

Next, for the strange class type redefinition error, I was instantiating the class variable in many files. So, I removed that feature of instantiation everywhere and went with global variable something like this.

File named as myHeader.h

```
#include "myFile.h"
myClass myObj;
```

And in all the other files

```
#include "myHeader.h"
myObj.function1( );
myObj.function2( );
```